# Camera low light effect (night mode)

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Trying to added Low light or Night mode in my iOS App's Camera

this is the code i've tried but it makes the camera very laggy

```
 device!.setExposureModeCustomWithDuration(device!.activeFormat.maxExposureDuration, iso: maxISO, completionHandler: nil)
 device!.setExposureTargetBias(device!.maxExposureTargetBias, completionHandler: nil)
```

tried

```
automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable
```

but doesn't really work.

Trying to make as good as instagram/snapchat like low light camera effect. Haven't really found the actual way or the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the best method but try adding a bright filter when pressed on Moon icon, when the photo video is taken keep the filter so that the processed image or video comes out as brighter.

Comment: wow thanks, this kind of seems to work, not sure why only1 answer i got but anyway it worked.